# How i can apply sub query in join

Tags: sql

Here is my tables given below:

**userDetails table :**

```
userid      name
 1          A   
 2          B
```

**Logs table :**

```
Id          requesterId         ApproveId
1               1                   2
```

I am trying this the following query :

```
select * from userDetils.name as Requester,**(What i can do here to get approver name)**
from Logs
join userDetail on Logs.requesterId = userDetails.userid
```

**Problem :**

How i can get requester and approver name

as

```
Requester   Approver
  A           B
```

Comment: You have to join twice with the userDetails table, once for Requester and once for Approver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
requester.name as Requester,
approver.name as Approver
from Logs as l
join userDetail as requester on l.requesterId = requester.userid
join userDetail as approver on l.ApproveId = approver.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select requester.Name as Requester,
       approver.Name as Approver
from Logs log
join userDetail requester
on requester.userid = log.requesterId
join userDetail approver
on approver.userid = log.approverId
```

You can join twice on the same table, using a different clause.